# Sitecore restful API authentication not returning token

Tags: api, sitecore, sitecore8

In Sitecore, I have an item and I want to access that item through API.
so I found this document:
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html

I'm trying to authenticate it through Postman using "https:///sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login"
Response status is 200 OK.[Response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwHiI.png)
[Login Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2rGq.png)

But nothing is coming back, no token, no error nothing.
[Postman response on login no token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZzWH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get a Cookie back. 
Set “`Content-Type: application/json`” in the request header.
and use somethings like this

```
{
    "domain": "sitecore",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "b"
}
```

If you have a self-signed certificate turn  the `SSL certification verification` OFF in Settings/General from the top menu in Postman.

Tip on https://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/documentation/Sitecore%20Services%20Layer/Play%20with%20Item%20Services/ you can download Postman file with the correct setting to do a login.

Answer (score 0):

The auth/login API required Https only (not http).
If you are running your website locally, you can easily create Self-Signed Certificate and then you can bind your site with HTTPS.

Just follow couple of simple steps,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkI3BJVxSgo

Then call https://[hostname]/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login API by passing Sitecore user credentials in request body from Postman.
Then Sitecore APIs will return the correct data with 200 response if we call those APIs from same machine.

Then you can call https://[hostname]/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/logout to clear auth cookies.